# Android Studio not recognize mouse clicks

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open Android Studio I cant use the mouse, the only way to use some options is using Tab + Enter, but even trying like this a lot of options is not working correctly, this is how that looks. The blue lines show which one is selected using Tab

Setup: MacOS m1, Ventura 13.3.1, Android Studio Doplhin 2021 3.1

[image]

Comment: Update or reinstall the Android Studio.